# Introduction on implementations of CPython types

Tags: python

I'm interested in a high level introduction on the implementations of CPython types, e.g., list, str, dict, etc., and their computational complexity. I only found this article which gives an intro on the list type.

http://www.laurentluce.com/?p=271

Comment: For computational complexity, see http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity. For implementations, well, this sounds harsh but the source code is a pretty good reference if you can read C (especially for dicts, half of that file is comments explaining the genius behind the implementation).

Comment: The blog you link to has (very good) posts on int, str, and dict implementations as well list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a nice [table](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on the python wiki listing the time complexity for a bunch of python types.  Furthermore, Laurent Luce blog also describes the implementation of python's [list](http://www.laurentluce.com/?p=271) and [dict](http://www.laurentluce.com/?p=249) types.